# Model attribute not available after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf `index.html` where I access my model attribute in a standard way:

```
<body>
<th:block th:text="${myModel}"></th:block>
</body>
```

Now I'm execute an `ajax request` and get another `html part` from my controller and set it to my `index.html`.

```
 @GetMapping(value="/part")
 public String getPart(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("somePart", "hello partial html!");
     return "part";
 }
```

The ajax request and the page rendering works as expected. But in this part of the html I'm not able to access my previous set `${myModel}`. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Why would it be available. It is an AJAX request, asynchronous is the keyword here. It happens in the background, you will get something back (if it is a `@Controller` a rendered piece of HTML which you would have to replace in the page using some javascript.

Comment: @M.Deinum I do replace the part of the html using javascript. If I rethink its clear why its not available, because the index is already rendered and its just html anymore. So the only way would be to save it to a js variable if I need the value. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

First sorry I am using my phone. 
XHR requests don't behave the same as regular Http requests in Spring MVC. It's a little difficult to get a model attribute with Ajax because Ajax doesn't expect a view (where the model injects its data). You have 2 choices to solve your problem.

1- The easiest way, add directly your data in the response body, annotate your handler with '@ResponseBody' and return the data you want not a view name.

2- A bit twisted, your handler method should return a 'ModelAndView' but Ajax will receive the full view, when I say "full view" I mean all the text inside the view where you want to render your model.

I'll edit this answer to add some codes if you don't see what I mean.

**CODE**

I did the test :

```
@GetMapping( "/part" )
public ModelAndView getPart( Map<String, String> model ) {
    model.put( "somePart", "hello partial html!" );
    return new ModelAndView( "part", model ); // part = the view name
}
```

The view code `part.html`:

```
<div>
   <h1>This is the view containing the model : ${somePart} </h1>
   <p>With other information....</p>
   <p>Please note that this view doesn't contain neither "head" nor "body" tags</p>
</div>
```

Ajax call : **EDIT 2**

```
$(function(){
    var myModel = "${myModel}"; //get the value of your previous model
    $.get("part",function(data){
        $("div.show-part-view").html(data);//in index.html add a div tag with class="show-part-view"
        $("p.my-model").html(myModel); // in the part.html view add <p class="my-model">...
});
```

In `index.html` add the `<div class="show-part-view">...</div>` where you want.

Result :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGzgg.jpg

Comment: I do get my model attribute using ajax request. I dont have access to my model attribute of my index.html.

Comment: Use the 2nd solution or place your attribute in the view using Jquery

Comment: I will try that. But if you have time. Can you please provide an example.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But this is what I already did. The question is how I  access my model attribute of my previous rendered index.html.

Comment: I edited the answer, put the model attribute in a JS variable, then you can put it where you want.